# Convenient strategies for assertion checks

Tags: c++, testing, assert, assertions

Some asserts are costly, some are better turned off at production code. 
At least it is not clear that assertions should be always enabled.

In my application I would like to be able to turn on/off part of assertions on per-file or per-class basis.

How to do it in C++?

Comment: turning on/off at compile-time or run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deactivating asserts module-wide i'd use:

```
#if defined(assert)
#  undef assert
#  define assert(x) ((void)0)
#endif
```

... of course this can be simplified if you are okay with using a custom macro.

```
#if defined(_NO_ASSERTS)
#  define myAssert(x) ((void)0)
#else
#  define myAssert(x) assert(x)
#endif
```

For class-wide deactivation i'd use a static const class member or a class-wide enum in combination with a custom macro:

```
#define myAssert(x) do { if(_CLASS_ASSERT) { assert(x); } } while(0)

class AssertOff
{
  enum { _CLASS_ASSERT = 0 }
}
```

With enums and static const bools all modern compilers should optimize away the `if(_CLASS_ASSERT) {}`.

Comment: Good idea with the enum. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To code with assertions considers good style of coding.

**As for runtime** turning on/off  You may do that with Boolean variable. For example in your code you can do the following:

Define a variable which will be used to indicate if assertions are turned on or off in a global namespace (for example out of your main() function in the same file).

```
bool  turnOnAssertions;
```

Define a variable as written below in other files where you want to turn on/off your assertions:

```
extern bool turnOnAssertions;
```

So by manipulating the turnOnAssertions variable with the UI and writing

```
if(turnOnAssertions)
assert(…);
```

you can turn on/off some of you assertions!

**As for compile time** you should do the following:

For you compiler you should give a flag like –DASSERTIONSON (-Dflag_name [flag name you can set anything you want])

```
#ifdef ASSERTIONSON 
bool turnOnAssertions = true;
#else
bool turnOnAssertions = false;
#endif
```

And just use the variable.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To disable assertions for a C++ file, you could do one of the following:

- Define the `NDEBUG` constant near the top of the source file.
- Add the `-DNDEBUG` to the compilation options for the source file.

Most IDEs and/or build infrastructure allow you to specify build options per file, so this is an easy solution.

Turning off assertions on a per class basis is more difficult when multiple classes are mixed into the same source file, or you have a lot of inline functions in your header files. You can of course `#define NDEBUG` and `#undef NDEBUG` in the relevant places.

Since some IDEs expect to be able to set `NDEBUG` for non-debug builds, you could make it more extensible, by choosing your own macro name, such as `DISABLE_ASSERT`. Then include code like like the following in a common header file (that isn't precompiled):

```
 #ifdef DISABLE_ASSERT
 #define NDEBUG
 #endif
```

Comment: `#define NDEBUG` can have other undesired side-effects besides disabling asserts.